# Convert a file to static C string declaration

Tags: python, c, string, file, unix

I would like convert number of files to static string declarations in C. I have trying writing a quick script in Python (shown below), but it doesn't seem exactly simple and a number of issue came up trying to compile the output.

```
import os, sys
from glob import glob
from re import sub

test_dirs = ('basics', 'float', 'import', 'io', 'misc')
tests = sorted(test_file for test_files in (glob('{}/*.py'.format(dir)) for dir in test_dirs) for test_file in test_files)

def cfunc_name(t):
  return sub(r'/|\.|-', '_', t)

for t in tests:
  print("void {}(void* data) {{".format(cfunc_name(t)))
  with open(t) as f:
    lines = ''.join(f.readlines())
    cstr = sub('"', '\\"', lines)
    cstr = sub('\n', '\"\n\"', cstr)
    print("  const char * pystr = \"\"\n\"{}\";".format(cstr))
    print("end:\n  ;\n}")

print("struct testcase_t core_tests[] = {")

for t in tests:
  print(" {{ \"{}\", test_{}_fn, TT_ENABLED_, 0, 0 }},".format(t, cfunc_name(t)))

print("END_OF_TESTCASES };")
```

Looking for an existing tool is not exactly obvious (may be my search keywords are not quite right)... Is there a simple UNIX tool that does this or has anyone come across something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work for you? https://code.google.com/p/txt2cs/

The main issue I can think of is new lines and escaping if you want to roll your own.

Comment: Non-printing/control characters (you mentioned newline) and the right character encoding are also important.

Comment: I managed to hack around newlines and inner double quotes, but getting compiler errors like _"hex escape sequence out of range"_ is a bit of extreme with wich I really don't want to deal with (unless I have to).

Comment: I really think you would be better off using the project linked (it is not my project). The code you posted really is so far off the mark. `sub('\n', '\"\n\"', cstr)` should be `sub("\n", '\\n', cstr)` Second your code doesn't replace the backslash. If I was writing something I would replace these: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape plus any character that was not between 32-127. Please note that the \xHH syntax can only encode a *byte* i.e. 0-255 - so be careful of python's Unicode handling, unless you use \u or \U instead

Comment: @teambob, I probably will, although I might translate it to python to keep my build system simple. I briefly thought that I could scarifies readability of the generated temporary code and attempted something with `def escape(s): return ''.join(["\\0{}".format(ord(x)) for x in s])`, which resulted in complete bullshit... and there is the 32-127 and hell knows what else etc... anyhow thanks for the pointer, I'll use it one way or another!

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? The unicode handling is different in each

Comment: This may also be helpful - conversion using sed: http://blog.markloiseau.com/2012/05/convert-text-file-to-a-c-string/

Answer (score 0):

I have used the `txt2cs` implementation as a reference and ended-up with just a few lines of Python that do all the escaping. As I didn't want to add extra things to the build system, it's easier to have this done in Python. This is going to be integrated in test automation, which is already a complex beast.

The main takeaway is that RE substitutions have to be done in a certain order and aren't the ideal tool for this purpose.

```
import os, sys
from glob import glob
from re import sub

def escape(s):
  lookup = {
    '\0': '\\0',
    '\t': '\\t',
    '\n': '\\n\"\n\"',
    '\r': '\\r',
    '\\': '\\\\',
    '\"': '\\\"',
  }
  return "\"\"\n\"{}\"".format(''.join([lookup[x] if x in lookup else x for x in s]))

def chew_filename(t):
  return { 'func': "test_{}_fn".format(sub(r'/|\.|-', '_', t)), 'desc': t.split('/')[1] }

def script_to_map(t):
  r = { 'name': chew_filename(t)['func'] }
  with open(t) as f: r['script'] = escape(''.join(f.readlines()))
  return r

test_function = (
    "void {name}(void* data) {{\n"
    "  const char * pystr = {script};\n"
    "  do_str(pystr);\n"
    "}}"
)

testcase_struct = (
    "struct testcase_t {name}_tests[] = {{\n{body}\n  END_OF_TESTCASES\n}};"
)
testcase_member = (
    "  {{ \"{desc}\", {func}, TT_ENABLED_, 0, 0 }},"
)

testgroup_struct = (
    "struct testgroup_t groups[] = {{\n{body}\n  END_OF_GROUPS\n}};"
)
testgroup_member = (
    "  {{ \"{name}/\", {name}_tests }},"
)

test_dirs = ('basics', 'float', 'import', 'io', 'misc')

output = []

for group in test_dirs:
  tests = glob('{}/*.py'.format(group))
  output.extend([test_function.format(**script_to_map(test)) for test in tests])
  testcase_members = [testcase_member.format(**chew_filename(test)) for test in tests]
  output.append(testcase_struct.format(name=group, body='\n'.join(testcase_members)))

testgroup_members = [testgroup_member.format(name=group) for group in test_dirs]

output.append(testgroup_struct.format(body='\n'.join(testgroup_members)))

print('\n\n'.join(output))
```

Below is what the output looks like, as you can see the initial `""\n` and `'\\n\"\n\"'` make it quite a bit more readable:

```
void test_basics_break_py_fn(void* data) {
  const char * pystr = ""
"while True:\n"
"    break\n"
"\n"
"for i in range(4):\n"
"    print('one', i)\n"
"    if i > 2:\n"
"        break\n"
"    print('two', i)\n"
"\n"
"for i in [1, 2, 3, 4]:\n"
"    if i == 3:\n"
"        break\n"
"    print(i)\n"
"";
  do_str(pystr);
}
```